# Angular how to enable/disable form but prefer attribute value on single controls?

Tags: angular

Let's see the next simple code snippet

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app'
    template: `
<form #form>
   <input name="car" [(ngModel)]="car" [disabled]="true" />
   <input name="bottle" [(ngModel)]="bottle" />
   <button (click)="form.disable()">Disable Form</button>
   <button (click)="form.enable()">Enable Form</button>
</form>
`
})
class AppComponent {
    car: string;
    bottole: string;

}
```

if click on enable/disable the state of the form will be updated and the `[disabled]` attribute on the `car` input will be ignored.

In my code, I have create `appForm` directive to manage state of controls on the form, f.e.

```
<form appForm [disabled]="canEdit"></form>
```

and in directive in `ngOnChanges` if disabled changed the `form.enable()/form.disable()` called, but there is an issue, that like on the first code snippet above, all the controls disabled, and [disabled] bindings are ignored.

Is it possible somehow to enable/disable form, but with `disabled` attribute higher prioirity for children controls? I thought about something like this

```
if(disabled) {
    this.form.disable();
} else {
    this.form.enable();
}
this.form.updateDisableStateFromAttributes();
```

So for clarity if it is the first code snippet, then `enable/disable` buttons should enable/disable all controls, but the car should be always disabled, because attribute `disabled` is set to true

Comment: Your directive can check for attributes on its ElementRef.nativeElement or using @Attribute

Comment: @WillAlexander thank you, sorry possibly my question was not clear enough, `form.enable()` will make all controls in the form enabled, but as in the first snippets some controls inside form can me marked as disabled via attributes. So I need to get all children controls and get their attributes, but controls has no reference to it native element, the control itself is an abstraction

Comment: Your `appForm` directive is on the `<form>` element, so it has access to its nativeElement (and therefore to all of its children). Sure it's not pretty, but the Angular best practice is to abandon HTML attributes completely when using reactive forms. Any reason you're not doing so?

Comment: @WillAlexander I had some doubt if I should iterate over children of form's nativeElement, as I need somehow to map the formControl instance with the tag in dom tree, custom controls are also used. I think I will try to use `name` for mapping, possibly it will work for my case.